# Access Javascript class fields in class methods

Tags: javascript, oop

Opposed to my expectation I can't access my class field *myLibrary* in the class method *initialize()*.

```
class ViewController {
      myLibrary = new Library();
      initialize() {
        console.log(myLibrary); // undefined
```

The only "solution" I found was to declare myLibrary outside of the class as a global variable. Is there a way to declare fields in a class and then, well, use them?

Comment: `this.myLibrary`…?

Comment: Side note: If this really is a View controller, then it would be a singleton. In that case, do you really need the class? Can't you just create it as an object with properties and methods?

Comment: You may want to read the documentation, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes - while the example about [field declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#field_declarations) is not the brightest one, it already shows that even in the constructor you would need to use `this` to access member variables.

Comment: @deceze `this` may or may not refer to the instance of `ViewController` that OP has initialized.  This depends on the context in which it is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript classes do not work the same way as Java classes.

To access properties on an object **you need to state the object** and then access a property on it. They aren't treated as variables in the current scope.

Inside a method, the keyword `this` will give you the associated object. (See [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) for a less simplified explanation).

So you need `this.myLibrary` instead of just `myLibrary`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
class Library {
  …
}

class ViewController {
  constructor() {
    this.myLibrary = new Library();
  }

  log() {
    console.log(this.myLibrary);
  }
}

const viewController = new ViewController();
viewController.log()
```

Comment: Is there any difference between declaring public properties outside and inside the constructor?

Comment: Yes, it is a matter of scoping. Who has access to the property/variable and also who can modify it.